# How I can find direction vector of line if I know only two angles (azimuth and polar) and one start point(x0,y0,x0)?

Tags: calculus, geometry, vector-fields, reflection

I have one start point x0,y0,z0, and two angles. Theta(polar(0-180)) and Phi(azimuth (0-360)). And now I need to find the direction of the vector of the reflected line 3d space box with parameters (4,5,6)

I tried to calculate using geometry formula and use cos and sin, adjacent, and opposite. But it gave me the wrong answer for my further cycle calculation I suppose I need some equation to write. Some kind of i, j, k. I could not calculate the slope as I don’t have enough input.

Comment: The title of a question should not be its first sentence.

Comment: "reflected" about what ?  You need to clarify your question a little bit more.

Comment: @Nathalieissweetandawesome reflected ray from the surface. I don't know how to find equations using only two angels and one point.

Comment: What is "3d space box with parameters (4,5,6)" ? What does that mean ?

Comment: @Nathalieissweetandawesome Box with parameters x=3, y=5, z=5. Ray will reflect inside of this box